# Remove or add an item to list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I have to design a function `removeOrAdd :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. My straightforward solution:

```
removeOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeOrAdd x xs | x `elem` xs = [x' | x' <- xs, x' /= x]
                 | otherwise   = x : xs
```

However, I have a feeling that I am doing something that has already been done by others. Is there any function in Haskell that already does it?

---

**UPD:** Let's see list as a `Set` we don't expect to have more than one `x` in a list, otherwise we remove all of them.

Comment: I'm not aware of any function that does this, and I'm not sure why one should need to exist. Adding an element to a list and removing one or rather different operations, and as you've proved, it's not at all hard to do oneself if you do want this. (Note that the result of the first case can be simplified to `filter (/= x) xs`)

Comment: What if `x` occurs multiple times? Do you want to remove all these items, or only the first/last one?

Comment: Hm... I do not expect to have more that one x. So let's see it as a Set. Let me update question.

Comment: @mkUltra In that case, you might want to [`nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:nub) the list on every call. Regarding the list comprehension, there's [`delete`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:delete) :-)

Comment: @Bergi I've got your point about `nub`, I want to preserve the list structure without `nub` it each time because It's a part of persistence record so in the trusted perimeter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any function in Haskell that already do it?

Not as far as I know no, and a search on [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Eq%20a%20%3D%3E%20a%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D) does not immediately lists such function. I think it is rather strange, since usually one aims to either add, or delete, but not both depending on a condition.

We can improve the above function, by making it more lazy (such that it works on infinite lists where `x` never occurs), as well as more efficient in the sense that we do not iterate twice over the list. We can use explicit recursion for this:

```
removeOrAdd :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeOrAdd x = go
    where go [] = [x]
          go (y:ys) | x == y = ys
                    | otherwise = y : go ys
```

We here thus iterate over the list, we keep iterating until we find an element `y` that is equal to `x`. If that is the case, we return `ys`, and we are done, since we removed that item. If not and we reach the end of the list with the recursion, we know `x` was not part of the list, and thus we return `[x]` to add that element. Here we thus add the elements at the *end* of the list.

If the list is sorted, we can insert it at the correct place:

```
removeOrAdd :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
removeOrAdd x = go
    where go [] = [x]
          go (y:ys) | x == y = ys
                    | y > x = x : y : ys
                    | otherwise = y : go ys
```

Here we thus keep the items in the correct order.

Comment: You might want to highlight the difference that in contrast to the OPs code you're adding the element at the end of the list. (Not that it matters when they treat the list as a set)

Comment: Thanks, guys! The recursion optimization looks good, in my case doesn't matter the position of an item so add at the end of the list it's fine.